# I had done when you had come by the evening

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

We have **"A"** and **B** moments in the past. **"A"** happened first, **"B"** happened second. **"A"** should be in Perfect. Example:

**I had done when you came**

**I had done - "A"**

**When you came - "B"**

**"A"** happened before **"B"**

If now we have **"B"** and **"C"** where **"B"** happened before **"C"**, then **"B"** should be in Perfect, **"C**" - in Past Simple(if it's a verb). Example:

**You had come by the evening**

**You had come - "B"**

**By the evening - "C"**

Now we have **"A"**, **"B"** and **"C"**. **"A"** should be in Perfect because it happened before **"B"** but **"B"** simultaneusly should be in Perfect, either, because it in its part happened before **"C"**. It's like if we have **"A"** and **"D"** where **"A"** is just **"A"** but **"D"** is **["B"+"C"]**. Example:

**I had done when you had come by the evening**

**I had done - "A"**

**When you had come - "B"**

**By the evening - "C"**

When you had come by the evening - **"D" ["B"+"C"]**

Congratulations? Well done? Can I be proud of myself?:D

Comment: What is it that you're actually asking? First of all, *I had done* doesn't make any sense. You need to say *what* you had done. The dishes? Your homework?  Also, your sentence is only one acceptable form. It could also be *I had done the dishes when you came by **in** the evening.*

Comment: Alright, let it be "dishes", but what if you came not 'in the evening" but "by the evening" what to do then?

Comment: It's very awkward to hear just *came by the evening*, without the ***in***. The other meaning I can think of would be better expressed as *came by **before** evening* or just *came **before** evening*, both dropping the article.

Comment: "in the evening" will mean "while evening" but I want to say "by, before evening". It's a right hint for Past Perfect, if something happened in the Past before something in the Past, too, isn't it?