# When you had found it out by 11 am I had already come?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Can we say so:

**I found it out at 11 am ?**

It's Past Simple. The action happened while it was 11 am

Can we say:

**I had found it out by 11 am?**

It's Past Perfect. The action had happened before 11 am.

But the trouble is if we want to mention some action which had happened even before this very action which had happened before 11 am:

**When you had found it out by 11 am I had already come?**

Meaning like I came before you found it out before 11 am.

But **"had come**" is in Past Perfect because happened before **"had found out"** while **"had found out"** is in Past Perfect, either,  because had happened before **"11 am"**.

Why is it wrong and why can't I use it? Such logic suits here perfectly.

*P.S. I know there has already been a similar topic but maybe here I showed what I meant in a different, more understandable way, I don't know...*

Comment: "Why is it wrong and why can't I use it?" It's not wrong, and you can use it.

Comment: Then what was wrong with "I had done when you had come by the evening"?

Comment: You've already asked about *come by the evening* [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206434/i-had-done-when-you-had-come-by-the-evening). You keep confusing tenses with syntax. ***If*** I *ignore* the syntax altogether (which makes it ungrammatical) but pay attention *only* to the tenses used, then that sentence is fine—albeit uncommon (*I had . . . when you came* would be more natural.)